Find $\mathbb{E}[\det(A-A^T)]$ if $a_{ij} \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$
Let $A$ be a random matrix, which elements take values $1$ and $0$ with probably $p$ and $(1-p)$ respectively. What is $\mathbb{E}[det(A-A^T)]$?
When dimensionality of $A$ is odd, $det(A-A^T) = 0$, as $A-A^T$ is skew-symmetric matrix with odd dimensionality.
However, I cannot find answer for even dimensionalities. Simulation suddenly shows that $E[det(A-A^T)](p)$ is similar to Gaussian function with $\mu = 0.5$.
Above is the graph for dimensionality 8.

You should read the community guid lines and edit your post, I really wanna hear what people answer, and you'll be more likely to get an answer and not downvoted to hell that way.

This is very similar to a problem addressed by this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3420505/154826 which addresses the $p = 0.5$ case.
Indeed, the reasoning is identical until we compute $\mathbf{E}[B_{12} B_{21}]$, where $B = A - A^{\mathrm{T}}$.
In the general $p$ and $2n$-dimensional case, this is
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[B_{12} B_{21}]
= -\mathbf{E}B_{12}^2
= -\mathbf{E}(A_{12} - A_{21})^2
= -2 p(1-p),
\end{align*}
whence
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E} (\det B)
= (-1)^n (2n-1)!! \mathbf{E}[B_{12} B_{21}]^n
= \frac{(2n)!}{n!} p^n (1-p)^n.
\end{align*}
In your $2n=8$ case, this is $(105/16)p^4(1-p)^4$, which renders the $p = 0.5$ point as $6.5$, which looks like it corresponds to your graph pretty convincingly!
